# WHERE STATEMENT IN SQL

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL (only about a week of practical experience).  The below statement works.  All I need to do is put in a prompt which allows the user to enter a start date and an end date.  The query will then pull that information.  I don't know how to incorporate that on the end of the where statement.  Hopefully this is easy.

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT JOBS.JOB) AS Number_of_Jobs, 
       COUNT (DISTINCT SAMPLES.sampnum) AS Number_of_Samples, 
       clients.csa
FROM Jobs 
    INNER JOIN Clients ON jobs.client = clients.client 
    INNER JOIN Samples ON samples.job = jobs.job 
WHERE 
    jobs.jobstatus = 'NEW' OR jobs.jobstatus = 'REPORTED'
GROUP BY
    CSA
```

Comment: On which programming language are you developing?

Comment: where and how are you executing/running this query?

Comment: Where do you call this query from? SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: from where do you intend to input the start date and end date?

Comment: I am using SQL 2008.  The query is a view in our advantage DB.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's unfortunately not so easy as you hope. SQL has nothing common with UI concept, it's just a query language.
All other stuff like dialogs must be implemented by means of programming platform you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a method for the user to call the procedure/code.

```
@DateFrom datetime = DATEADD(dd,-7,GETDATE()),
@DateTo datetime = GETDATE()

WHERE yourDateColumn BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
```

or

```
WHERE yourDateColumn >= @DateFrom AND yourDateColumn < @DateTo
```

Answer (score 0):

well if this is MS sql, first make it into a stored procedure.

then add parameters abit like

```
USE [your db]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[storedprocname]
@datefrom as datetime,
@datetoo as datetime,
AS
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT JOBS.JOB) AS Number_of_Jobs, COUNT (DISTINCT SAMPLES.sampnum) AS   Number_of_Samples, clients.csa
FROM Jobs INNER JOIN Clients ON jobs.client = clients.client INNER JOIN Samples ON  samples.job = jobs.job 
WHERE jobs.jobstatus = 'NEW' OR jobs.jobstatus = 'REPORTED'  AND (date => @datefrom and date <= @datetoo)
GROUP BY CSA
```

you can then call this stored procedure in an application and pass the datefrom and date too that a user provides.  that is if there is an application.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT JOBS.JOB) AS Number_of_Jobs, 
         COUNT (DISTINCT SAMPLES.sampnum) AS Number_of_Samples, 
         clients.csa
  FROM Jobs,Clients,samples
  where jobs.client = clients.client   AND
  samples.job = jobs.job  AND 
  yourDateColumn >= @DateFrom AND yourDateColumn < @DateTo   AND

   (jobs.jobstatus = 'NEW' OR jobs.jobstatus = 'REPORTED' )

    GROUP BY CSA


   Try this one,  I don't know your dates,  i except one date between from date and to   
   date from db   then

   yourDateColumn >= @DateFrom AND yourDateColumn <= @DateTo
```

Comment: Sorry I don't see in that statement where the start date and end date are entered?  My basic query works, I don't know how or where to add the enter start date/finish date

Answer (score 0):

Ideal solution would be -

```
USE [YOUR_DB_NAME]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME] (
    @BeginDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME
)
AS

SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT JOBS.JOB) AS Number_of_Jobs, 
       COUNT (DISTINCT SAMPLES.sampnum) AS Number_of_Samples, 
       clients.csa
FROM Jobs
INNER JOIN Clients
    ON jobs.client = clients.client
INNER JOIN Samples
    ON samples.job = jobs.job
WHERE 
    (jobs.jobstatus = 'NEW' OR jobs.jobstatus = 'REPORTED')
    AND YOUR_END_DATE_FIELD BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY CSA
```

1. Create a stored procedure - somthing like what is mentioned above -
2. Capture the date range from your front end
3. Create a SQL connection from your code and execute this stored procedure with parameters as your begin & end dates.

Let us know the language & paltform your are using at the front end for more details.